# page not show after issuing zf command

Tags: php, zend-framework

just simple question, recently i have setup a web server to build project using zend framework, after setup and see those welcome page saying that you are creating websites powered by zendframework, then i try issuing command,

```
$ zf create controller alert
```

i get the message that saying that i've successfully create controller, view and so on, but when i try to navigate to the page by URL, ex:

```
www.mywebapp.com/alert
```

the page is broken, i've check those tuts but none of them showing this case. can some one define which step i've skip?

update: (25/5/2010)

so i've found that there is no problem, is just that i've not configured properly my route to my web apps, so i have to type URL like this:

```
www.mywebapp.com/index.php/alert
```

how am I going to change this? i mean i want to explode "index.php" out of URL.

Comment: Double check mod_rewrite to be enabled & check .htaccess is exist ......... then try to read apache error log to get more info about the error

Comment: Also, elaborate on "the page is broken".  It doesn't load, or it loads incorrectly, there's a crash, etc, etc

Comment: it is broken due to browser cannot find that pages, maybe i should check what you have suggest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled. You can call phpinfo(); to see a listing of your servers configuration. Then in that page search for mod_rewrite. If its not check with your server admin.
Also make sure you have a .htaccess file in your public folder containing at the minimum:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```